# Вывод текста js в html

Tags: javascript, html, css

У меня есть код в js, который получает дату, но мне нужно сделать так, чтобы эта дата выводилась на страницу, с сохранением всего форматирования в css

```
Year = Data.getFullYear();
Month = Data.getMonth();
Day = Data.getDate();

switch (Month) {
    case 0: fMonth="января"; break;
    case 1: fMonth="февраля"; break;
    case 2: fMonth="марта"; break;
    case 3: fMonth="апреля"; break;
    case 4: fMonth="мае"; break;
    case 5: fMonth="июня"; break;
    case 6: fMonth="июля"; break;
    case 7: fMonth="августа"; break;
    case 8: fMonth="сентября"; break;
    case 9: fMonth="октября"; break;
    case 10: fMonth="ноября"; break;
    case 11: fMonth="декабря"; break;
}
var today = "Сегодня " + Day + " " + fMonth + " " + Year + " года"
document.getElementById('dataclass').insertAdjacentHTML(today)
```

CSS:

```
    font-family: 'Arial Black', sans-serif;
    width: 170px;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-top: -9.7%;
    transition: all .7s ease-in;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="dataclass"><h4 class = "data">data</h4></div>
```

Comment: Проблема не ясна. ............ также замечу `<div class="dataclass">`  и `document.getElementById('dataclass')`

Comment: Кратко. Он не выводит этот текст. Он выводит только слово прописанное в тэге h4
Без слова, просто пустое место.

Comment: В js пытаешься вставить элемент с ИДЕНТИФИКАТОРОМ, а в html у тебя элемент с КЛАССОМ

Comment: Поменял. Суть не поменялась, он по прежнему ничего не выводит.

Comment: Приведите полный код. В js объект Date, может быть в этом дело. но в данном виде у вас работать не будет ничего точно. Ну про класс и ID уже писали. var date = new Date(); var Year = date.getFullYear(); var Month = date.getMonth(); var Day = date.getDate(); var fMonth; switch (Month) { case 0: fMonth="января"; break; case 1: fMonth="февраля"; break; case 2: fMonth="марта"; break; case 3: fMonth="апреля"; break; case 4: fMonth="мае"; break; case 5: fMonth="июня"; break; case 6: fMonth="июля"; break; case 7: fMonth="августа"; break; case 8: fMonth="сентября"; break; case 9: fMonth="октября"; bre

Comment: Что имено ты поменял и на что?

Comment: ```<div class ="data" id="data"><h4 id = "dataclass">data</h4></div>
```
```var today = "Сегодня " + Day + " " + fMonth + " " + Year + " года"
document.getElementById('data').innerHTML(today)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Ошибка #1**: В js пытаешься вставить элемент с **идентификатором**, а в html у тебя элемент с **классом**

**Ошибка #2**: если посмотреть **[документацию](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)** внимательно, то метод `insertAdjacentHTML` требует **ДВА** аргумента, а не один. Первый из них - позиция вставки

```
<!-- beforebegin -->
<p>
<!-- afterbegin -->
foo
<!-- beforeend -->
</p>
<!-- afterend -->
```

а вот только вторым - элемент для вставки

Answer (score 0):

почти все замеченные ошибки и правки пометил комментом.

```js
var preMonth = [
    "января",
    "февраля",
    "марта",
    "апреля",
    "мае",
    "июня",
    "июля",
    "августа",
    "сентября",
    "октября",
    "ноября",
    "декабря"
];
var preWd = ["вс", "пн", "вт", "ср", "чт", "пт", "сб"];
var d = new Date(); /* !!!!! нет объекта - нет методов */
var Year = d.getFullYear(); /*!!!*/
var Month = preMonth[d.getMonth()]; /*!!!*/
var Day = d.getDate(); /*!!!*/
var wd = preWd[d.getDay()];

var today = "Сегодня " + wd + ", " + Day + " " + Month + " " + Year + " года "; /*!!!*/
document.getElementById('x').innerHTML = today; /*!!!*/
```

```css
#x{ /* !!!!! */
    font-family: 'Arial Black', sans-serif;
    width: 170px;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    margin-left: 20%;
    /* margin-top: -9.7%; */
    transition: all .7s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<div class="dataclass"><h4 id='x' class="data">data</h4></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно вот так ка вариант:

```js
const date = new Date();
const Year = date.getFullYear();
const Month = date.getMonth();
const Day = date.getDate();


const fMonth = [
  "января",
  "февраля",
  "марта",
  "апреля",
  "мае",
  "июня",
  "июля",
  "августа",
  "сентября",
  "октября",
  "ноября",
  "декабря"
];

let today = `Сегодня ${Day} ${fMonth[Month]} ${Year} года`;

document.getElementById('data').append(today);
```

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}

.dataclass {
  font-family: 'Arial Black', sans-serif;
  width: 170px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  margin-left: 20%;
  margin-top: -9.7%;
  transition: all .7s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<div class="dataclass">
  <h4 class="data" id="data"></h4>
</div>
```